# Changing ip address of adapter

Tags: ip, adapter, static-ip

I am trying to change the IP address on a pc running ubuntu 16.04. The computer is not connected to the internet. I changed the /etc/network/interfaces file according to the instructions in the official documentation:

```
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
      address 192.168.86.220
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.86.1
```

I also added a network connection with the same details in the network UI.
I am able to ping the address that I configured, however, when running ifconfig the following address is shown:

```
enp4s0
 address 192.168.0.2
 Bcast 192.168.0.255
 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Cannot copy the full text as I cannot establish an internet connection on the other computer due to lacking wifi capability and no wired connections available. If this is actually needed I will make the effort.

I am also able to ping the 192.168.0.2 address at the same time as the address that I configured for the same adapter.

What else is needed to change the IP address of my adapter?

Comment: welcome to [ubuntu.se]  Did you reboot or better: restart the network interface for the change to come into effect?

Comment: I tried that multiple times. What finally solved it for me was changing the interfaces.d, if i remember correcly, file and changed the ip adres to what i needed it to be, after a restart it worked. Deleting the other methods and implementations did not revert it.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer in the box below and accept it in 48 hours and then leave a comment here @Fabby and I'll come back and upvote!  **;-)**  *Share your knowledge!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by altering the /etc/network/interfaces.d file.
In this file the ipaddress that I was trying to alter was specified. After changing it here the ip address changed on the next start up. The reason why this is working is still unknown to me. The system was not connected to the internet.

When I switch to my dual boot ubuntu 16.04, with an internet connection, the interfaces.d file is empty. So not a definitive solve but something to try.

Comment: Please add the contents of the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` as you have included the contents of  `/etc/network/interfaces` in the question above. It will be useful to others to see what these two files look like for the working solution.